# django obtain related manager with unknown name

Tags: django, django-models

Trying to make my app reusable and compatible with custom user models, I've encountered the following issue:

Let's say the User model is the following:

```
class Member(AbstractUser):
    pass   # basically the builtin User with another name
```

As a result of this code from `django.contrib.auth.models`:

```
class PermissionsMixin(models.Model):
    """
    A mixin class that adds the fields and methods necessary to support
    Django's Group and Permission model using the ModelBackend.
    """
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(_('superuser status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates that this user has all permissions without '
                    'explicitly assigning them.'))
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, verbose_name=_('groups'),
        blank=True, help_text=_('The groups this user belongs to. A user will '
                                'get all permissions granted to each of '
                                'his/her group.'))
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission,
        verbose_name=_('user permissions'), blank=True,
        help_text='Specific permissions for this user.')

class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):  # <- included there
    ....
```

(Notice that the many to many `groups` doesn't define a `related_name`.)

Now, when working with groups I can't do this:

```
group.user_set.add(...)
```

because the reverse `RelatedManager` name is actually `member_set`.

Note that the the model's name is `Member` in this case but it could be any other.

Right now, I'm doing the following:

```
getattr(group, "%s_set" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.split('.')[-1].lower())
```

Yeah, quite ugly.

Question: Any common or bultin solution for this?

**EDIT with my final implementation:**

```
@classmethod
def _get_user_reverse_field_name(cls):
    User = get_user_model()
    cls._user_reverse_field_name = User._meta.get_field('groups').related.get_accessor_name()

@property
def members(self):
    if not hasattr(self, '_user_reverse_field_name'):
        self._get_user_reverse_field_name()
    return getattr(self, self._user_reverse_field_name)
```

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood the question, removed my answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
In [1]: opts = Group._meta

In [2]: from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model()

In [3]: rel = [r for r in opts.get_all_related_many_to_many_objects() 
               if r.model == get_user_model()]

In [4]: rel
Out[4]: [<RelatedObject: users:user related to groups>]

In [5]: user_rel = rel[0]

In [6]: user_rel.get_accessor_name()
Out[6]: 'user_set'
```

Comment: That looks promising. The only problem I see is that `AUTH_USER_MODEL` doesn't necessarily have to inherit from `User` or `AbstractUser` or anything. Any way to filter `get_all_related_many_to_many_objects()` with the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` string (`'app_label.model_name'`)?

Comment: I've adjusted my answer to your needs...`get_user_model()` is nicer than having to deal with the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` string...

Comment: Yeah I see. That gives me circular import issues :/ My custom `Group` model in in the same models.py as the default `User` model that I want to provide with my app.

Comment: A trick to avoid circular imports for models is getting them from django's model cache: `from django.db.models.loading import cache;
User = cache.get_model('auth', 'User')` or move the import/getting from cache inside the method/function..

Comment: Well, I think I've found the best solution. You've given me the final clue with the `get_all_related_many_to_many_objects`. Thanks to that I've found how to obtain the `RelatedObject` straight from the `User` model. Otherwise my custom Group model could only have one many_to_many with the `User` model.

Comment: I'll edit my OP with my final code. Give it a check if you're interested, I didn't need cache thanks to properties.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `inspect` to loop through all apps and models before they are loaded. Within that loop you could monkey patch the field's `related_name` attribute if the model is a subclass of `AbstractUser`.

Having said that, it would be pretty darn nasty. Did I mention it would fail when you have two models deriving from `AbstractUser` as the related names would clash?

Your current way of achieving this is pretty straight forward and a one liner, I'd keep it.

Well I'd probably prefer `.format()` over `%`

For an in depth understanding how the reverse relationship works have a look at the descriptor in  [related.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/related.py)

Comment: Hello, thx for the answer. Yeah, I've thought about the monkey patching. But soon discarded it when I noticed what you said. It would somewhat break the `AbstractUser`. And that's obviously not worth it just for clearer code. I imagine there might be an undocumented `_meta` attribute, an internal method or something :/

Comment: I'm reading the code in related.py and `get_accessor_name()` seems exactly what I wanted. Is it possible to have access to that method?

Comment: Well I'm not sure that function will be called before the relationship is accessed, you could patch the the descriptor's method and see if you're dealing with a model that derives from `AbstractUser`. Anyway you'd probably want to keep away from patching _that_ deep into Django's core.

Comment: I think I got it. `Member.groups.field.related.get_accessor_name()` is returning "member_set".

Comment: The problem now is obtaining the user model class from my group model. I think I would have issues with the order of INSTALLED_APPS :/